# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [7] failed to fetch metadata: generic::permission_denied

Tags: google-cloud-build, google-artifact-registry

Which role should I grant my cloud build service account to resolve this error :

`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [7] failed to fetch metadata: generic::permission_denied`

I get this error when trying to deploy Django to GAE from cloud build.